# Generating an $ARMA(1,1)$ model with `arima.sim` in R, receiving warnings and errors but questioning the flaw in my method for estimation

Tags: r, arima, prediction, aic

So I wanted to generate $500$ data points from an $ARMA(1,1)$ distribution in R, use the first $400$ as my training data and use the training data and the `predict` function to both see if I could obtain the correct model via AIC and then plot my prediction. I wanted to generate a whole bunch of different $ARMA$ models to use for the AIC which is why I basically built a grid, however I get a bunch of warnings and errors with my current method, despite the fact it seems to work. Note it is the estimation and not the actual prediction that raises the problems. Can I use a grid like so to produce AICs for various model types?

```
####### ARMA(1,1) ############
# Causal stationary - root of the function phi(z) > 1
theta1<- 0.5
phi1<- 0.6

arma11<- arima.sim(n = 500,list(ar = c(phi1), ma = c(theta1)), sd = sqrt(1))
tr.data<-arma11[1:400]
AIC<-c()
for (i in 0:3){
  for (j in 0:3){
    aic.ij<- arima(tr.data,order = c(i,0,j))$aic
    AIC<- c(AIC,aic.ij) 
  }
}
AIC<- matrix(AIC, ncol=4, byrow =T)
colnames(AIC)<- c("q=0","q=1","q=2","q=3")
rownames(AIC)<- c("p=0","p=1","p=2","p=3")
AIC
index<-which(AIC==min(AIC),arr.ind=T)
index
prd<-predict(arima(tr.data, order = c(index[1]-1,0,index[2]-1)),n.ahead =100)
vld.data<-arma11[401:500]

# plot the training data with the next 100 predictions and the 95% confidence intervals
plot.ts(arma11, xlim=c(0,500),ylim=c(floor(min(arma11)),ceiling(max(arma11)))) 
lines(prd$pred, col='blue')
lines(prd$pred-(1.96*prd$se), col='red')
lines(prd$pred+(1.96*prd$se), col='red')
```

For this particular $ARMA$ I am error free but receive various size mismatch errors with other models under the same method, I receive this warning though.

```
Warning message:
In arima(tr.data, order = c(i, 0, j)): possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1Warning message:
In arima(tr.data, order = c(i, 0, j)): possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1         q=0      q=1      q=2      q=3
p=0 1608.907 1296.137 1207.432 1187.231
p=1 1244.182 1178.820 1180.004 1181.993
p=2 1190.716 1180.072 1182.002 1183.776
p=3 1179.731 1181.688 1183.767 1181.305
    row col
p=1   2   2
```

Comment: Are there two separate warning messages? It looks like a line break is missing. Is all the text in the second block part of the error message (including the lines `p=0...`, `p=1...`, `p=2...`, `p=3...`, `row col`, `p=1...`)? `Optim gave code = 1` just means that the estimation procedure did not converge, which can happen for different reasons.

Comment: Also, you do not seem to be generating data "by hand" because you use the function `arima.sim`, and you get errors not while generating but while estimating; you could edit your title accordingly.

Comment: @RichardHardy that's exactly what it looks like in my compiler for some reason, a little strange. So the warning isn't a concern, this method looks alright?

Comment: Not, it's not alright. You cannot trust the estimates then. You may try varying the options for arguments `methods`, `SSinit` and `optim.method`. Function `Arima` from "forecast" package may be slightly more robust, but I am not sure.